# Router configuration. Sharing the same network over two interfaces

Tags: networking, network-interface, router

I have a router, R, and two hosts, A and B. They are all running Ubuntu 22.04.
I have both physical access and necessary permissions to all machines involved in the setup and I would like to ssh from B to A.

My initial setup involved:

- Connecting A to R via an ethernet cable (IP assigned: 192.168.0.2).
- Connecting B to R using a wireless network (IP assigned: 192.168.0.51).

**The problem**:
I cannot connect from B to A. Host A seems to be unreachable from B.

Would anyone be able to help diagnose the issue, are there certain configurations or settings that I need to modify on the hosts or router?

Thanks, I'll be glad to provide more info when needed

**EDIT 1**:

here is the output of IP route from A, B and the router R.

```
userk@hosta:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 100

userk@hostb:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 20600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.226 metric 600

userk@router:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev lanbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1
```

**EDIT 2**:

```
userk@router:~$ ip -details link show lanbr0
13: lanbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:37:88:50:d8:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65535 
    bridge forward_delay 1500 hello_time 200 max_age 2000 ageing_time 30000 stp_state 0 priority 32768 vlan_filtering 0 vlan_protocol 802.1Q bridge_id 8000.f6:37:88:50:d8:bd designated_root 8000.f6:37:88:50:d8:bd root_port 0 root_path_cost 0 topology_change 0 topology_change_detected 0 hello_timer    0.00 tcn_timer    0.00 topology_change_timer    0.00 gc_timer  167.77 vlan_default_pvid 1 vlan_stats_enabled 0 vlan_stats_per_port 0 group_fwd_mask 0 group_address 01:80:c2:00:00:00 mcast_snooping 1 mcast_router 1 mcast_query_use_ifaddr 0 mcast_querier 0 mcast_hash_elasticity 16 mcast_hash_max 4096 mcast_last_member_count 2 mcast_startup_query_count 2 mcast_last_member_interval 100 mcast_membership_interval 26000 mcast_querier_interval 25500 mcast_query_interval 12500 mcast_query_response_interval 1000 mcast_startup_query_interval 3125 mcast_stats_enabled 0 mcast_igmp_version 2 mcast_mld_version 1 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 


userk@router:~$ ip link show | grep master
6: lan0@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lanbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
7: lan1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lanbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
8: lan2@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lanbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
9: lan3@eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lanbr0 state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

If I add wlan0 to the bridge then to the previous output the following line is appended:

```
11: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lanbr0 state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
```

Now when I connect to the Wifi network I can see the other host A connected over ethernet and I can ssh into it!

I noticed the following files in /etc/systemd/network

```
userk@router:~$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/network/21-lanbr-bind.network 
[Match]
Name=lan0 lan1 lan2 lan3

[Network]
Bridge=lanbr0
```

I added wlan0 to the list of interfaces in 21-lanbr-bind.network and is looks to set the interface in the bridge at startup. That's good!

There is a dedicated file for wlan0

```
userk@router:~$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/network/30-wlan0.network 
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
#ConfigureWithoutCarrier=true
BindCarrier=eth0

#static setup
Address=192.168.0.1/24
Gateway=192.168.0.1
DNS=192.168.1.1

IPForward=yes
DHCPServer=no
```

Is this file creating any conflicts? And is BindCarrier=eth0 correct or needed?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `ip route` on all three systems? Can you successfully connect to both A and B *from R*?

Comment: Sure I ll update the question. Yes I am able to connect from R to A and B.

Comment: From the router, please post the results of "arp -an"

Comment: Hi @BruceMalaudzi!  The OS image that I am using for this router has a bunch of configurations and the "arp -an" command output is very large. What @LawrenceC suggested worked

Comment: Hi @A.B! "That won't work like this." How am I supposed to set it up?

Comment: Nah from what you wrote, I made a bad assumption so you can forget my earlier comment (that I'll remove). So the router is the AP.

Comment: Oh don't worry, I am happy to modify my approach and improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sharing the same network over two interfaces

You are supposed to use a switch or bridge to do that.  Of course - what do you do when one link is wired and the other is wireless?

Linux can junction two physical interfaces into a virtual bridge (e.g. software switch).  This is common on plastic home routers (is that what this is?)

> 192.168.0.0/24 dev lanbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1

This looks like it might already be a bridge.  Confirm by running this:

`ip -details link show lanbr0`

If you see the word "bridge" in there, then it is.

Run this to find out what's already junctioned to it:

`ip link show | grep master`

Each line here is a link that's in a bridge and it will tell you which bridge it is in (hopefully you do not have more than `lanbr0`)

I am betting the following is true: You have an enp3s0 (wired link) or similar in `lanbr0` but not `wlan0`.

- Add `wlan0` to `lanbr0` - `ip link set dev wlan0 master lanbr0`
- `wlan0` won't have an IP and that's normal - `lanbr0` is now both your wired and wireless junctioned on layer 2 like a switch.
- Whatever DHCP server your wired is using, your wireless will now use.
- If still not working, disable AP isolation.

Comment: Thanks LawrenceC for your input. Yes confirmed, lanbr0 is a bridge.
I am adding an Edit to the question

Comment: Looks like the problem is solved! However, I noticed a dedicated .network file for wlan0 in /etc/systemd/network and I am not sure whether the configuration is safe or if it creates conflicts with this setup